# Configuring Robolectric, Android Studio and Gradle to take a test Application

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying Android Studio 0.5.8 with gradle.

My current root build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.novoda.gradle:robolectric-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }
}
```

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    dependencies {
        androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
        androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
        androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}

task addTest {
    def src = ['src/test/java']
    def file = file("app.iml")

    doLast {
        try {
            def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(file)
            def node = parsedXml.component[1].content[0]
            src.each {
                def path = 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}"
                def set = node.find { it.@url == path }
                if (set == null) {
                    new Node(node, 'sourceFolder', ['url': 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}", 'isTestSource': "true"])
                    def writer = new StringWriter()
                    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(parsedXml)
                    file.text = writer.toString()
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // nop, iml not found
        }
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(addTest)
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class"
}
```

and this is my test Application class:

```
public class NSApplicationTest extends NSApplication {

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return mock(Context.class);
    }

    @Override
    public AlarmManager getAlarmManager() {
        return mock(AlarmManager.class);
    }
}
```

The problem with this configuration is that the task `addTest` is loading even the NSApplicationTest class as test and it's failing with an:

```
   com.pack.scheduler.app.NSApplicationTest > initializationError FAILED
        java.lang.Exception  

So I tried to change the name extension to see if this would fix everything but I'm still getting the same error. Then I tried with @Ignore on NSApplicationTest.

Unable to load JUnit4 runner to calculate Ignored test cases
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AllExceptIgnoredTestRunnerBuilder$FallbackJUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(AllExceptIgnoredTestRunnerBuilder.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.IgnoredTestDescriptorProvider.getAllDescriptions(IgnoredTestDescriptorProvider.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestEventAdapter.processIgnoredClass(JUnitTestEventAdapter.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestEventAdapter.testIgnored(JUnitTestEventAdapter.java:92)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$6.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:175)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:61)
        at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestIgnored(RunNotifier.java:172)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredClassRunner.run(IgnoredClassRunner.java:16)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.junit.internal.runners.InitializationError
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.assertValid(MethodValidator.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.validate(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:37)
        ... 39 more
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need write your own TestRunner. Just use the correct naming schema for your test application class: TestNSApplication (instead of NSApplicationTest)

Often I see following pattern:

- *Test marks test execution classes
- Test* marks class extensions for make a class testable

I expect you already know that this class must have the same package as your application class.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently I solved it using a custom runner:

```
public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends TestLifecycle> getTestLifecycleClass() {
        return MyTestLifecycle.class;
    }

    public static class MyTestLifecycle extends DefaultTestLifecycle {
        @Override
        public Application createApplication(final Method method, final AndroidManifest appManifest) {
            return new TestNSApplication();
        }
    }
}
```